# FindById and update or push based on what is found

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

in the following code I am attempting to search for a conversation with a given ID, then I want to find an object within that conversations' `staffTyping` Array that has the same sender ID as the one sent in (there will never be more than 1 object in this array with the given senderId) and then just update the dateTime field in that object to have a `new Date`. If there is not an object in the `staffTyping` array where the `senderId` field matches the sent in senderId, I would like to add a new object to the array with that senderId and new Date. I would then need to save the conversation and res.send the result. Thanks!

```
Conversation.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: req.body.conversationId, 'staffTyping.senderId': { '$eq': req.body.senderId}},
    {senderId: req.body.senderId, dateTime: new Date}, // do I need to specify here I am referring to info inside the staffTyping array?
    {new: true, upsert: true},
    async function (error, doc) {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Conversation not found' });
      } else {
        res.send(doc);
      }
    }
  );
```

Conversation Model

```
{
    "messages": [
        "5e9e7b1f1378751f459313af",
        "5e9e7b3c1378751f459313b0"
    ],
    "staffTyping": [
        {
            "senderId": "1",
            "dateTime": "2020-04-21T17:00:58.913Z"
        },
        {
            "senderId": "3",
            "dateTime": "2020-04-21T17:00:24.187Z"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5e9e222f03ab480845302193",
    "clientTyping": true,
    "introMessage": "welcome homies!"

}
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB?

Comment: `upsert: true` is for creating a brand new document, not for adding  a value to an array.  Do you want to create a new document if the `req.body.conversationId` doesn't exist in the collection? If so, what should the other fields be set to?